# Use of "concur" in a formal context

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I am wondering if using "I concur" in a formal context is OK. I am writing a formal email; I want to use I concur, at the same time don't want to sound ghetto. Maybe I shouldn't bother and use *I wholeheartedly agree* instead. I still want to learn if it is OK to use "concur" in a professional email.

Comment: *Concur* is a word I would never expect to hear uttered in a ghetto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Concur](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/concur)* and *agree* essentially mean the same, but the former is more formal. Make your choice accordingly.